# Asynchronous results (Promise) vs AJAX

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, asynchronous, playframework, playframework-2.0

So I'm using Play as my MVC framework. My web application simply does calls to a Postgres database to feed data to the views. I'm currently using AJAX in the view to get the data. I figured there are times when the database will lag a bit in sending the data so I would use AJAX to allow other elements in the view to load.

Now my question is, since I'm already using AJAX in the view, should I be using Promises in the controllers? Would it make a difference if I used Promises? I haven't had enough experience to figure out how having asynchronous actions both in the view and in the controller can affect my web application. My intuition says that the AJAX action is enough for a web application with about 100 - 150 hits a day.

What are your insights on this?

Comment: Since your datastore is Postgres, your DB calls are already synchronous.  Wrapping them in promises/futures isn't going to make much difference.  Moreover, unless you know for certain that this is your bottleneck, it's probably not worth optimizing.

Comment: Hmm, very good point as I forgot to consider the database. But let's say that each AJAX call makes it's own DB connection. Wouldn't that in a way be "asynchronous"?

Comment: No, because you're still blocking a thread and consuming resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of non-blocking I/O and Promises is not about speed or latency, but about [better use of resources](http://www.ustream.tv/recorded/42801712). By default, Play gives you one thread per CPU core. This works very well when all of the work you're doing on those threads is extremely fast - that is, you avoid expensive computations and use only non-blocking I/O. However, all JDBC calls are synchronous, so they will block the few available threads for a long time, and if you have enough traffic, any new requests will have to queue up, increasing load time for your pages.

Therefore, whether you should use Promises - or, more accurately, a separate thread pool - for DB calls has nothing to do with whether you make those DB calls on the initial page load or via AJAX calls. It's simply about how much traffic you expect, how many threads you have, and how long you'll be using each thread. For most applications, the best practice is to run DB calls on a separate thread pool so they don't block the main worker threads.

For example, configure a thread pool (ie, ExecutionContext) in `application.conf` as follows:

```
  akka {
    actor {
      db-context {
        fork-join-executor {
          parallelism-factor = 20.0
          parallelism-max = 200
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Then use that thread pool in your DB code:

```
  def dbLookup(someId: Int): Future[SomeDbValue] = {
    val dbExecutionContext = Akka.system.dispatchers.lookup("db-context")
    Future {
      // DB code to fetch SomeDbValue
    }(dbExecutionContext)
  }
```

See [Play Framework Thread Pools](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ThreadPools) for full instructions and [Play Framework: async I/O without the thread pool and callback hell](http://engineering.linkedin.com/play/play-framework-async-io-without-thread-pool-and-callback-hell) for more background info.

Comment: Perfect. Your article is very insightful from having just briefly skimming through it. Looking forward to reading the rest of it. And the Play's documentation pretty much laid out the issue I was having in my head. Thank you for this.